# Why does this selection sort code shows different output when running again as compared to first time

Tags: c++, g++, selection-sort

Firstly when I have code this program it was running perfectly but running it again, it is not showing expected output can someone tell what's wrong with it

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    int loc,min;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1;i++){
        min = arr[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(min>arr[j]){
                min = arr[j];
                loc = j;
            }
            swap(arr[loc],arr[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: after `min = arr[i];` add `loc=i;`

Comment: Better still, don't save the values in `min` in the first place. That var is unnecessary. This is doable remembering only the location of the prospect minimum value, initially set to `i` before the inner loop, then used as the swap source *after* the inner loop rather than within.

Comment: @IłyaBursov still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgoing the fact that variable-length arrays are not part of standard C++ (and thus code tutorials that use them should be burned), the code has two main problems.

1. On an already sorted sequence, the inner-most `if` body will never be entered, and therefore `loc` will never receive a determinate value.
2. The swap is in the wrong place..

**Explanation**

Within your code...

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    int loc,min; // loc is INDETERMINATE HERE
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1;i++){
        min = arr[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(min>arr[j]){
                min = arr[j];
                loc = j; // loc ONLY EVER SET HERE
            }
            swap(arr[loc],arr[i]); // loc IS USED HERE EVEN IF NEVER SET
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The purpose of the inner loop is to find the **location** (loc) of the most extreme value (smallest, largest, whatever you're using for your order criteria) within the remaining sequence. No swapping should be taking place in the inner loop, and the initial extreme value location (again, `loc`) should be the current index of the *outer* loop (in this case `i`)

Therefore...

1. We don't need `min`. It is pointless.
2. We *must* initialize `loc` to be `i` before entering the inner loop.
3. We swap after the inner loop, and then only if `loc` is no longer `i`.

The result looks like this.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int loc = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[loc] > arr[j])
                loc = j; // update location to new most-extreme value
        }

        // only need to swap if the location is no longer same as i
        if (loc != i)
            swap(arr[loc], arr[i]);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `swap(arr[loc],arr[i]);` should be outside the inner for loop, so move it one line down.
Also, you will want to initialize `loc` to `i` at the start of the outer for loop.

Comment: can share edited code with me coz its not working as u told to do

Comment: I have accepted the answer that is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    int loc,min;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1;i++){
        min = arr[i];
        loc=i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(min>arr[j]){
                min = arr[j];
                loc = j;
            }
            swap(arr[i],arr[loc]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```